# MongoDB save and update array element

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this current value that I've saved

```
db.mycol.save({name:'elbren',lastname:'antonio',subjects:{}})
```

result:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("576db356332a8fc87bf769be"),
"name" : "elbren",
"lastname" : "antonio",
"subjects" : {

}
```

What I need is this result:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("576db356332a8fc87bf769be"),
"name" : "elbren",
"lastname" : "antonio",
"subjects" : 
{
    {
         code: "sub1",
         Description: "desc1",
         Unit: 3
     },
     code: "sub2",
     Description: "desc2",
     Unit: 3

}
```

What is the best thing to do on this which is I want to add subjects into that _id?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to update an already saved document? Or just create it "correctly" so that you get the second result instead of the first (meaning you need to know how to change the `save` argument)?

Answer (score 0):

To create the document so that you get the desirable result, just write it directly:

```
db.mycol.save({name:'elbren',lastname:'antonio',subjects:{
    {
        code: "sub1",
        Description: "desc1",
        Unit: 3
    },
    code: "sub2",
    Description: "desc2",
    Unit: 3
}})
```

If you want to change ("fix") the existing document, you have to use `update`:

```
db.mycol.update(
    { name : "elbren", lastname : "antonio" },
    { $set: { subjects:{
                  {
                      code: "sub1",
                      Description: "desc1",
                      Unit: 3
                  },
                  code: "sub2",
                  Description: "desc2",
                  Unit: 3
              }
    }}
);
```

Here `{ name : "elbren", lastname : "antonio" }` is a query that matches the document you want, and the second part is the [update parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Use "$push" operator to add array to current object.

```
// in php e.g:
['$push'=>['fild_value'=>array('mail=>'me@mail.com','tag'=>'personal')]]
```

More result this:

```
{
   "_id": 12345678,
   "fild_value": [
        {
        "mail":"me@mail.com",
        "tag":"personal"
         },
         {
          "mail":"job@mail.com",
          "tag":"worker"
          }
      ]
 }
```

MongoDB provide array operators ($push/$pull,$addToSet,$elemMatch,etc...)